# How to remove leading and trailing blanks from multiple column names in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame "Information" whose columns are as below

```
"  Name  "   " Age "   "Location  "   " Marital_Status "
Robert         24       LA              Single
Martha         32       CA              Married
```

All above column names are having leading/trailing blanks

I want to remove leading and trailing blanks from column names using single command.

Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

The new `trimws` is useful here

```
names(Information) <- trimws(names(Information))
```

Comment: I am not able to use this function. R says It is not available

Answer (score 0):

For example using `gsub`:

```
gsub("^ *| *$",'',c("  Name  " , " Age ", "Location  ", " Marital_Status ")
```

You can apply this to your data.frame's colnames:

```
gsub("^ *| *$",'',colnames(Information))
```